# Insert records for the rest of the year starting on current week

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, insert

I am trying to insert the same record for the rest of the year.

Since we are currently in week 13 of 2021, there are a total of 40 weeks remaining (including week 13).

Using the following code, I can get the current year and week:

```
define('NL', "\n");

$ddate = date("Y/m/d");
$date = new DateTime($ddate);
$currentyear = $date->format("Y");
$week = $date->format("W");

echo "Current Year: $currentyear", NL;
echo "Weeknumber: $week", NL;
```

The above will output the following:

```
Current Year: 2021
Weeknumber: 13
```

Here is my attempt using a WHILE loop to create INSERT queries with different week numbers:

```
$year  = $currentyear;

$firstDayOfYear = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $year);
$nextSunday     = strtotime('monday', $firstDayOfYear);

while (date('Y', $nextSunday) == $year) {
  $insert = "INSERT INTO history (`WEEK`, `YEAR`, `ADDDATE`, `USERNAME`) VALUES ($nextSunday, $year', NOW(), 'jbeasley')";
  
  echo $insert, NL;

  $nextSunday = strtotime('+1 week', $nextSunday);
}
```

Here is how the output looks:

```
 INSERT INTO history (`WEEK`, `YEAR`, `ADDDATE`, `USERNAME`) VALUES (1, '2021', NOW(), 'jbeasley')
 INSERT INTO history (`WEEK`, `YEAR`, `ADDDATE`, `USERNAME`) VALUES (2, '2021', NOW(), 'jbeasley')
 INSERT INTO history (`WEEK`, `YEAR`, `ADDDATE`, `USERNAME`) VALUES (3, '2021', NOW(), 'jbeasley')
 // and so on up to 52 (there are 52 weeks in 2021)
```

This is working for the most part, but it's also where I got stuck.

I'm not sure how to get the INSERTs to start on the current week, disregarding all previous weeks.  In this case, since we are currently in week 13, the first INSERT should start on week 13 followed by the remaining weeks, as follows:

```
INSERT INTO history (`WEEK`, `YEAR`, `ADDDATE`, `USERNAME`) VALUES (13, '2021', NOW(), 'jbeasley')
INSERT INTO history (`WEEK`, `YEAR`, `ADDDATE`, `USERNAME`) VALUES (14, '2021', NOW(), 'jbeasley')
INSERT INTO history (`WEEK`, `YEAR`, `ADDDATE`, `USERNAME`) VALUES (15, '2021', NOW(), 'jbeasley')
// and so on until the final week
```

Comment: You already know how to get the week: `$week = $date->format("W");`. You can add a simple `if` condition inside the loop that skips the insertion if the week is less than what you want.

Comment: This seems such a futile exercise. Why would you want to do this? Normally a "history" is in the past, not in the future. Why not only create data that actually means something?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - "History" is just the name of the table.  It's not technically storing history.

Comment: Semantics are important in development, too. Naming a table `history` when it doesn't contain history is just adding confusion to the system.

Comment: @El_Vanja - Understood.  I'll keep that in mind.  I'm still testing your suggestion.  Will revert shortly.

Comment: Please, learn to [use prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60496/9193372).

Comment: @Syscall - I am indeed using prepared statements.  This particular case was just for testing purposes. I do thank you.

Comment: Why explicitly write code to “disregard” previous weeks, why not just _start_ at the current week to begin with? `$nextSunday = strtotime('monday', $firstDayOfYear);` is the problem here, so fix it in that place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the suggestion from El_Vanja, I updated the WHILE loop to include an IF/ELSE to check if the current week is greater than the :

```
while (date('Y', $nextSunday) == $year) {
  if($week > date('W', $nextSunday)){
    echo "skip this week " . date('W', $nextSunday), NL;
    $nextSunday = strtotime('+1 week', $nextSunday);
  }
  else{
    $insert = "INSERT INTO history (`WEEK`, `YEAR`, `ADDDATE`, `USERNAME`) VALUES ($nextSunday, $year, NOW(), 'jbeasley')";

    echo $insert, NL;

    echo date('W', $nextSunday), NL;
    $nextSunday = strtotime('+1 week', $nextSunday);
  }
}
```

Using the above, the loop will skip the past weeks and only start creating the query on the current week.

Comment: @Syscall - Always nice to have a second set of eyes.  Thank you. Updated answer.